# Django: Test an Abstract Model

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, abstract-class

I have a simple abstract class and I want to write a unit test for this.
I am using Django 1.10 and the most [answers I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281670/django-best-way-to-unit-test-an-abstract-model) are out there for years and maybe are outdated.
I have tried the solution from [Vinod Kurup](https://www.kurup.org/blog/2014/07/21/django-test-models):

```
# tests/test_foo.py
from django.db import models
from django.test import TestCase

from ..models import MyAbstractModel

class MyTestModel(MyAbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myappname'

class AbstractTest(TestCase):
    def test_my_test_model(self):
        self.assertTrue(MyTestModel.objects.create(name='foo'))
```

Are there any simple modern approaches to test an abstract model that work with Django 1.10 like the one from Vinod Kurup?

**Edit:**

Code for my Abstract Model:

```
class FlagsModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    reported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And this is my test file:

```
from ..models import RecipeModel, FlagsModel

class FlagsTestModel(FlagsModel):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'recipes'


class FlagsModelAbstractTest(TestCase):

    def test_my_test_model(self):
        self.assertTrue(FlagsTestModel.objects.create())
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "recipes_flagstestmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: ...eported", "recipes_flagstestmodel"."deleted" FROM "recipes_f...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 72, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 549, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 499, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 743, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 78, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 122, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 79, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 118, in get_objects
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/arch/.environments/djanveg_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "recipes_flagstestmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: ...eported", "recipes_flagstestmodel"."deleted" FROM "recipes_f...
```

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: @Abdulafaja yep it says `No migrations to apply.`

Comment: did you run python manage.py makemigrations ?

Comment: @soupboy yep this one says: `No changes detected`

Comment: Ok, make sure that your app is in your's project INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

Comment: @Abdulafaja I have just checked it, it is already in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Please share the code for your abstract model.

Comment: As far as I know, Django does not generate migrations for models in tests. That's why this model does not exist in the database.

Comment: @elethan I have edited my question :-)

Comment: @Con Did you ever find a solution that works for testing abstract models?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't migrated that model to your database, and that's because you created the model inside the tests file, Django only checks for models inside the `models.py` file, so move the next code to the `models.py` file:

```
class FlagsTestModel(FlagsModel):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'recipes'
```

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py mgirate` to create the table inside your database and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I could do this, but I dont want to have my abstract model in my development database I just want to test it and want that Django only does it for my test db

Comment: @Con Maybe you could create the table first in that database and then add a Meta to your model, so it knows where to look :D