# What are the differences between setUpClass, setUpTestData and setUp in TestCase class?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing

More specifically, what are the use cases for each?

What I've understood so far:

## setUpClass

- This method runs once, before all the tests in a test class

## setUpTestData

- This method runs once if the DB has transaction support. Otherwise it runs before each test.

## setUp

- This method runs before each test in a test class.

From the understanding I mentioned above, it seems setUpTestData lies in the area between setUpClass and setUp. Why do we need a class level method for setuUpTestData while the same effect could be achieved by either `setUpClass` or `setUp` or a combination of the both?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

EDIT: Update/Correction after Alasdair's comment

#### setUpClass

- `setUpClass` is used to perform class-wide initialization/configuration (e.g. creating connections, loading webdrivers). When using `setUpClass` for instance to open database connection/session you can use `tearDownClass` to close them.
- `setUpClass` is called once for the TestCase before running any of the tests. Similarly `tearDownClass` is called after all the tests have run.

Note from documentation:

> SimpleTestCase and its subclasses (e.g. TestCase, ...) rely on setUpClass() and tearDownClass() to perform some class-wide initialization (e.g. overriding settings). If you need to override those methods, don’t forget to call the super implementation:

#### setUpTestData

- `setUpTestData` is used to create initial test data per TestCase. This method is called by TestCase.setUpClass() ([src](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/test/testcases/#TestCase.setUpTestData))
- `setUpTestData` is called once for TestCase, as explained in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#testcase). In case databases does not support transactions, `setUpTestData` will be called before each test run (thanks @Alasdair for correcting me)

#### setUp

- `setUp` will be called before each test run, and should be used to prepare test dataset for each test run.

Using `setUpTestData` allows for test performance improvement, be aware that change to this data in tests will persist between different test runs. If needs to be reloaded it can be done so from `setUp` method.
If database used for running tests does not support transactions, performance improvement is negated (as `setUpTestData` will be called before each test run)

Comment: That's not quite right. The [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method will only be called once if the database supports transactions. It is only called before every test if the database does not support transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mil4n. SetupTestData seems to have a similar use case as the setUp method. Or as Alasdair mentioned, the difference lies in transaction support in the DB. Am I correct?

Comment: Raiyan - I stand corrected! setUpData will be called only once to load initial data for the TestCase (or as @Alasdair stated)  setUp will be however called before each test. I'll update my answer