# Django initialize data test for all test classes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests

I need to add test to my django project, I need to create data test before execute tests. I read about setUp test data in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594519/8258902). I can create data in setUpClass for all test in a class. Creating my complete data test is time consuming approach so I want to run it once for all of test classes, is any approach to set up data for all test classes once?

Comment: You can create a base class for all your test classes and implement `setUpClass` and/or `setUp` there.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn It's worked, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I check it for 2 class that inheritance from my main test class, I create data test in main test class in setUpClass method, but it would re create data test for each inherited class, in previous comment I checked it for one inheritance test class. can explain more?

Comment: `unittest` supports only class-level and module-level fixtures (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule)). Neither of this approaches will probably work for you, so I'd recommend switching to `py.test`, where you can have fixtures with session scope.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my answer, hope it can help someone else. Base on django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner).

> A test runner is a class defining a run_tests() method. Django ships with a DiscoverRunner class that defines the default Django testing behavior. This class defines the run_tests() entry point, plus a selection of other methods that are used to by run_tests() to set up, execute and tear down the test suite.

In case of this question, there is 2 helpful methods in this class.[setup_databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_databases) and [teardown_databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.teardown_databases) so we can overwrite them to initialize data for all test classes.

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner as BaseRunner

class MyMixinRunner(object):
    def setup_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        temp_return = super(MyMixinRunner, self).setup_databases(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something
        return temp_return

    def teardown_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do somthing
        return super(MyMixinRunner, self).teardown_databases(*args, **kwargs)

class MyTestRunner(MyMixinRunner, BaseRunner):
    pass
```

after defining test runner class we need to add `TEST_RUNNER` to settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.MyTestRunner'
```

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer! What's the reason you decided to use a mixin instead of the regular inheritance?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember why I chose mixin, and now it's a mystery for me too :)

Comment: This question (and answer!) inspired me to write an [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-transactions-to-make-django-tests-run-faster-224fdd695bfd?source=friends_link&sk=ea34902c33bd1bcfdc40f4d820fdac34) on the two-level nested transaction mechanism of django testing framework. More details and some diagrams there. Will you have a look?

Comment: I read your article, It has more details that help to understand the topic better. I will be glad if you add a reference to this question on your article due to inspiration. :)

Comment: Actually this article was laying around as a draft since 2017 when I wrote about [transactions in django tests vs pytest](http://axil.github.io/pytest-vs-standard-django-tests.html). I didn't think back then that anyone else would need project-wide initialization. Your question told me that it might be interesting not only to me – so it was worth writing.

Comment: As for the answer it is basically the same as the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_databases) which is a more authorative source to quote.
And provided that your answer doesn't give clear distinction about interitance vs mixin it might make things less clear than they were. :)

Comment: As for the word "inspiration" I just wanted to cheer you up as I'm also a big fan of answering my own questions in hope that maybe one day it will help someone on the net :)