# Inherinting Django SetUpTestData method called for each child

Tags: python, django, django-testing

Inheriting a mother class make its classmethod `setUpTestData` called for each child class. This is what I excepted but not what I want.

Here is a minimalist example

```
from django.test import TestCase


class ParentClass(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.parent_attr = "parent value" 
        print("ParentClass.setUpTestData called") # this is called twice


class TestChild1(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(TestChild1, cls).setUpTestData()
        cls.child_attr = "child value 1"

    def test_child(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.parent_attr, "parent value")
        self.assertEqual(self.child_attr, "child value 1")


class TestChild2(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(TestChild2, cls).setUpTestData()
        cls.child_attr = "child value 2"

    def test_child(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.parent_attr, "parent value")
        self.assertEqual(self.child_attr, "child value 2")
```

```
$ python manage.py test accounts.tests.test_test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
ParentClass.setUpTestData called
.ParentClass.setUpTestData called
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.006s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I want to be able to make many child class where each child class would apply tiny modification to the common 'inherited' database. However I do not want to run many time the parent classmethod as it is very slow.

How can I ensure parent database is generated only once and that every child class works on a copy of parent database instead of regenerating the entire database.

Comment: I've digged a little bit and the problem seems way more complex than it first looked like. Django use a transaction for whole class with `setUpTestData` and inner transactions for each `setUp` method. If I want to use the same strategy (transaction then rollback) I have to respect inheritance tree structure as a test order if I want to have commons transactions between multiples Test class. So far my best solution seems to implement my Own Test Runner

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353962/django-initialize-data-test-for-all-test-classes) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have stated yourself and @brian-destura pointed out as well, your best option to share data between test classes would be implementing your own test runner.

The runner should inherit from `django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner`.
In that runner, you could override `setup_test_environment()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_test_environment)) or `setup_databases()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_databases)) depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Finngu's suggestion absolutely works. However - a big reason to split tests is to make them run in individual DB transactions. By sharing the database setup you're somewhat defeating the point.

To make **independent** tests that share a DB setup, you can just use `subTest`.

```
from django.test import TestCase
 

class TestSubTests(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(TestChild1, cls).setUpTestData()
        cls.parent_attr = "parent value"

    def test_subtests(self):
        
        with self.subTest("The first value"):
            child_attr = "child value 1"
            self.assertEqual(self.parent_attr, "parent value")
            self.assertEqual(self.child_attr, "child value 1")
 
        with self.subTest("The second value"):
            child_attr = "child value 2"
            self.assertEqual(self.parent_attr, "parent value")
            self.assertEqual(self.child_attr, "child value 2")
```

These subtests run independently - that means the test continues running if one subtest fails. This vs. the custom test runner is a decision that will boil down to details, but subtests are effective and sufficient in most cases. Read more on them i.e.: [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/05/29/subtests-are-best/).

Comment: SubTest does not create a transactionnal test block, wouldn't any operation on the database in the first subtest have repercusion in the second subtest? beside I loose inheritance.