# How to create a test-only Django model in general (and with pytest-django specifically)

Tags: python, django, pytest, abstract-class, pytest-django

**General issue:**
I have an abstract model that I want to test with a real model instance, however I don't want to have to completely restructure my project/test format. See these two answers for reference: [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/503435/10521417) [Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281670/django-best-way-to-unit-test-an-abstract-model?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I want to
**A)** Define models inside each test app folder and not define them inside the actual apps
**B)** Not have an additional/separate apps.py and settings.py configuration for each test folder.
I know this is possible because the django project has a very similar [test structure](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/tests/admin_changelist) like this, but they use a [test run script](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/tests/runtests.py) that I can't entirely decipher.

The test/ folder mirrors the app structure I have (which are blog/, projects/, richeditable/).

```
backend
├── projects
├── blog
├── richeditable
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── projects
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── richeditable
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_model.py
│   │   ├── models.py         <-------------- This defines a model that inherits from richeditable.models
```

```py
# richeditable/models.py
class Draftable(models.Model):
    blah = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

```py
# tests/richeditable/models.py
class DummyDraftable(Draftable):
    additional_field = models.BooleanField()

#   class Meta:
#       app_label = "some_app" 
#  ^--- Django does not seem to like having this blank and I don't know what to put to make this work
```

```py
# tests/richeditable/test_model.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def add_app(settings):
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS += ['backend.tests.richeditable']
    
# presumably the above fixture would affect the apps/models
# settings before the database is created, but that does not seems to be the case
def test_please_work(add_app, db):
    assert DummyDraftable.objects.create(blah=1, additional_field=True) is not None
```

---

My best guess from what I've seen of the [django project script](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/tests/runtests.py) is that they load in each folder for testing as a module and add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` at run time before the test cases. However,  you can't just simply change `INSTALLED_APPS` because models are being added and migrations have to be made to the test database beforehand as well as there seems to be a need to define an `AppConfig` (because Django loses it's mind if you don't). I've tried to include the `app_label` Meta field for models but it didn't work, or I may have done something wrong. But the point is, I don't see the script creating an `AppConfig` *and* they somehow don't have to declare `Meta` in their models.py

---

**Pytest specific stuff:**
Things get further complicated with pytest-django because it doesn't use Django's `TestRunner` interface. This is [how you would do it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/#using-the-django-test-runner-to-test-reusable-applications) if that were the case (note the order of operations). I have already tried modifying the `settings` pytest fixture before instantiating the db with the associated fixtures but this doesn't end up loading the module no matter what I do. From [looking at the source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/ed77ef2916013eaa7924ef6d21f7c8266ae4f670/pytest_django/plugin.py#L261), it seems like the settings are fixed in place based on what the settings.py specifies and modifying the `settings` fixture makes no difference to app loading.

---

Comment: Modifying `INSTALLED_APPS` after `django.setup()` was called has no effect anymore, as Django won't reload them. Create custom settings module for testing that inherits from the production one and modify `INSTALLED_APPS` there. You can then pass custom settings via `pytest-django`'s options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up solving my own issue. As @hoefling mentioned, the best way is to create a separate settings file that extends your normal settings file and specify that as your pytest settings file.

```
// pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --ds=config.settings.test
```

An important thing to note is that you cannot have your test modules be the same name as already existing apps, as I found out. So the structure I had with backend/tests/richeditable is not allowed no matter what you do. So I prepended each folder with `test_` and it works fine. This also solves the issue of having to include `app_label` in your models.

```py
# testsettings.py
from .settings import *  # noqa

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'backend.tests.test_projects',
    'backend.tests.test_blog',
    'backend.tests.test_richeditable',
]
```

```
backend
├── projects
├── blog
├── richeditable
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_blog
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── test_projects
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── test_richeditable
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_model.py
│   │   ├── models.py
```